# How do I display buttons in list items in a horizontal row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When I add a category as admin it will update with this code and display the categories that are currently in the database. However, I can't seem to align them next to each other.

```
@foreach ($categories as $category)
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 mb-5 text-center">
      <li><a class="btn btn-dark mt-auto" href="#">{{$category->category_name}}</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Have you tried removing the (invalid) `<li>` element?

Comment: You're rendering each `<button>` element in a `container > row > col` layout, which are block-level elements if using Bootstrap CSS. The `<li>` also makes no sense, as this is not in a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element. If you want each button in-line, you'll need to remove all the surrounding `<div>` elements, and just render the `<a class="btn btn-dark">` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue, aside from the faulty list structure, is that you're repeating containers. You should be repeating list items.

Then, use [Bootstrap's inline list class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/content/typography/#inline) to arrange list items horizontally.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 mb-5 text-center">
      <ul class="list-inline">
        @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <li><a class="btn btn-dark mt-auto" href="#">{{$category->category_name}}</a></li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```